# the meaning of "elsewhere"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of "elsewhere" in this sentence "Most units raised in Britain went elsewhere on the European continent, although one is recorded in Morocco."

Does it mean, all the soilders were sent to other places, except Europe. But there were still a portion of military were sent to Morocco, which was in Europe (Morocco was a exceptional nation in this case?)

## Here's the full text

The army also provided a mean of personal advancement for auxiliary soldiers recruited from the native peoples, as a man obtained hereditary Roman citizenship on retirement after service in an auxiliary regiment. Such units recruited on an ad hoc (as needed) basis from the area in which they were stationed, and there was evidently large-scale recruitment within Britain. The total numbers were at least 12,500 men up to the reign of the emperor Hadrian (A.D. 117-138), with a peak around A.D. 80. Although a small proportion of the total population, this perhaps had a massive local impact when a large proportion of the young men were removed from an area. Newly raised regiments were normally transferred to another province from whence it was unlikely that individual recruits would ever return. Most units raised in Britain went elsewhere on the European continent, although one is recorded in Morocco. The reverse process brought young men to Britain, where many continued to live after their 20 to 25 years of service, and this added to the cosmopolitan Roman character of the frontier population. By the later Roman period, frontier garrisons (groups of soldiers) were only rarely transferred, service in units became effectively hereditary, and forts were no longer populated or maintained at full strength.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elsewhere means at other places or unspecified places apart from the one being named. So in your example Britain is named and elsewhere in European continent means places other than Britain. It further says on European continent so it means units were placed at other locations other than Britain on European continent. If the European continent was not specified it would have meant anywhere else in the world other than Britain.

Answer (score 1):

It means that most of the soldiers from Great Britain went to other European countries, although there were exceptions: one unit was actually spotted in Morocco. Which is in Africa, just south of the Gibraltar.

Comment: Could I say, most of the soldiers were sent to Europe countries, such as Italy, Germany, Holland, France, .... Except part of them were sent to Morocco. I didn't aware of that Morocco is part of Africa,  sorry about that.